# linear combination of infinitely divisible random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

If $X$ and $Y$ are real valued random variables with infinitely divisible distributions, does $aX + bY$ also have an infinitely distribution ($a, b \in \mathbb{R}$). I've seen this stated in several places as obvious, but I have only seen the proof in the case that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Does anyone know where I can find the proof if we don't assume independence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that is true in general.
Counter example: Let $W_1$ be a standard normal random variable, and

$W_2 = W_1,\ \text{if}\ |W_1|\le 1$

$W_2 = -W_1,\ \text{otherwise}$

Then $W_2$ is also a standard normal r.v., but $W_1+W_2$ has a finite support, and is not constant, therefore not infinitely divisible, according to

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwiowYfs3srKAhXEMyYKHaM1DskQFggzMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.abo.fi%2Ffak%2Fmnf%2Fmate%2Fgradschool%2Fsummer_school%2Ftammerfors2011%2Fslides_rosinski.pdf&usg=AFQjCNE_2G83w4nq7gqDM5xvP3pt8c281A&cad=rja

Comment: Thanks, I kind of thought it might not be true. Which theorem in that document are you referring to?

Comment: At the bottom of page 4. Actually, it is an intersting result. I think it can be proved using the relationship btw infinitely divisible distribution and Levy process, but I guess there should be some more elementary approach.